# I'm looking to buy a laptop specifically for recording audio

Tags: laptop, audio, recording

So I am a voice actor and need to get a laptop **SPECIFICALLY** for recording audio.

Are there any recommendations for software and hardware, or does it really not matter in the long term what kind of laptop I use?

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs.

Comment: Frankly, for voiceover, even if over a stereo or even 5.1 playback track, the computer is the least of your worries. You could use a 2002 Pentium 4 & still get away with it. Good mic & USB preamp ought to be your prime concerns. Keep your sights on a Neumann U87 & all else will pale into insignificance, even your choice of preamp ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a high spec laptop to do audio recording. As a standard I'd suggest an i5 processor and 4gb RAM minimum. If you want to manipulate the audio then you may need higher specs. The most important thing you'd need is a microphone, if you're on a budget then i'd suggest a blue yeti microphone. For software if you're on a tight budget then I'd suggest audacity which is a free audio recorded and you can run some basic manipulations. For a more professional software, use Adobe Audition which is part of Adobe Creative Cloud. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, I was under the general impression that I wouldn't need a high spec laptop solely for audio recording, and that a mic was more important, but I figured I'd rather find out before actually buying.

Say money wasn't an object and I wanted something that I could get the most out of for audio recording and would last a while. Is there anything in particular you'd recommend?

Comment: I'm nowhere near an expert in this area but there are several useful sites around at the minute like this one: http://bit.ly/1JE12oW Another tip is to watch some youtubers and find the one who's audio you like best and see if they've listed their set up. It mainly comes down to personal preference to be honest.

Comment: Huh, righteous.
Well I appreciate your help. You're the bomb, man.

Comment: Happy to help :)